# How to import a project which you just deleted in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I just deleted a android project in eclipse.
But now i want to import it again but it keeps saying:

Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that the project folder is still existing in your project workspace folder. You could cut it and paste it somewhere else, then import it. Or you might be lucky and refreshing the folder in eclipse is enough.

Answer (score 8):

When you delete a project in eclipse you get asked if you also want to delete the folder contents. If not, the project folder remains in the workspace folder.
You can re-add it with **File->Import** and then choose **General->Existing Project into Workspace**.

Answer (score 4):

Uncheck **copy project into workspace** checkbox while importing existing projects.

Answer (score 0):

New project->android project->create project from existing source
Or
import->general->existing projects into workspace
should do the trick.

Comment: nope didnt worked, same warning.. cut+paste project somewhere else worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I could not re-import projects from eGit into my workspace, even though I had moved these projects to another hard-drive!  What I ended up doing is renaming my **workspace** directory to **workspace_OLD**, and had Eclipse recreate it.  It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions provided here I found it expensive.
Just deleting the project from eclipse(package explorer) wont solve the problem.

**i took my project in pen drive and then deleted it from my computer hardrive i.e even from recycle bin. and then re-imported it.** One thing to be noted is that even though I have changed the name of project that I backed up, still after importing it appeared with the same name which is **managed on cvs**